# Привязка названий к числам

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Есть МФО банков и названия банков. (где то штук 1000) . Есть поля ввода

```
<input type="text"  id="mfo" name="mfo" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
<input type="text"  id="bank" name="bank" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
```

Есть таблица в mySQL с полями mfo, bank (думаю тут всё ясно) Собственно вопрос как можно сделать так чтоб когда пользователь вводит МФО банка в поле с айдишником mfo то поле с айдишником bank автоматически заполнялся с названием банка . Можно даже показать пример не связанный с mysql а текстовым файлом. Буду очень признателен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если совсем по простому , то можно просто через словарик ассоциаций через тот же JSON/

```js
var jsonMfo = JSON.parse($('#json-mfo').text());
//слушаем, что вводят в форму
$('#mfo-code').on('keyup', function() {
  var code = $(this).val();
  //если за таким кодом закреплен банк, выводим егол название
  var bankName = (jsonMfo[code] || 'Invalid mfo code');
  $('#bank-name').text(bankName)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Для примера, сюда вставляем json c кодами и наименованиями банков -->
<div style='display:none' id='json-mfo'>{"11":"bank A" , "12":"bank B" ,"13":"bank C"}</div>
<input placeholder='insert mfo code(11,12,13)' type='text' id='mfo-code'>
<strong id='bank-name'></strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаёте файл `php` в котором получаете методом `GET` или `POST` значение `mfo`. Затем находите в таблице значение `bank` по заданному `mfo` и возвращаете значение `bank`.

В этот созданный `php` файл обращаетесь каждый раз `ajax`-ом при заполнении поля с `id="mfo"` и полученный от файла ответ вставляете в поле с `id="bank"`.

Что же в этом сложного?